# proguard not work with jni (native string)

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, proguard

*PROBLEM:*

enabling proguard on android studio together to jni not possible to complete the project because of this error:

Note: there were 11 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members

*SOURCE CODE:*

jni code:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_example_example(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

  return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "example");

}
```

java code:

```
public native String example();
```

*TRIED:*

1) add on proguard rules :

```
-keep class *  {  // I also tried to put the class one by one instead of *

 native <methods>; // or  "*;" , "public native <methods>" , "public *;"

}
```

2) add on proguard rules (successfully build , activity not start on device)  :

`-ignorewarn`

Comment: Can you share your class name & java package id? (maybe the problem is that you are not declaring your JNI function the correct way)

Comment: application package id is app.myapplication (app full work without proguard)

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is simple - you need to change the C function like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_app_myapplication_example(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

  return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "example");

}
```

Comment: already and so this was an example, my problem is enable proguard (with jni show error Note: there were N accesses to class members by means of introspection. You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members

Comment: Did you try adding: -keep class app.myapplication.* { *; } to your proguard-rules.pro?

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

Comment: Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.

Comment: Note: there were 1 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
      (using '-keep').

Comment: If this is an example app - do you really need proguard? If yes, could you share which libraries you are using and maybe your gradle. If no maybe just turn proguard off and see if you still have an issue.

Comment: proguard work on project without jni , That is just one example in reality I have to apply on a different project but that based on the same .c code and java